# Increase same column value from multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, increment

I'm using the blow query to update a column in multiple rows:

```
UPDATE table SET col = 
(case 
    when id = 1 then 10
    when id = 2 then 20
    when id = 3 then 30
end)
```

And I know if I want to increase the `col` value I should do this:

```
UPDATE table SET col = col+10
```

But it doesn't work for updating **multiple** rows.
I also tried:

```
when id = 1 then (@col := @col + 10)
```

But this doesn't work too.
Anyone knows how can I concatenate these two with each other and **increase one column's value in multiple rows in mysql ?**

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you right:

```
UPDATE table SET col = col +
(case 
    when id = 1 then 10
    when id = 2 then 20
    when id = 3 then 30
end)
```

Comment: Yes that was easy enough! But I don't know why I didn't pay much attention! TNX anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking for this?

```
UPDATE table SET col = if(@col is null, @col := col+10, @col)
```

or this?

```
UPDATE table SET col = if(id = 1, col+10, if(id = 2, col + 20, col + 30))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but @Lashane told the answer :)